# PUT/Edit MIME email content with microsoft graph

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api, mime

Graph API allows me to get the MIME content of email calling following graph api request: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages//$value .

Is there a plan to support PUT operation to allow changing of contents of email this way?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if there are plans for this. You can make your voice heard here:
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/search?filter=ideas&query=MIME%20content I'll let folks know about your request. Post your link to your user voice request here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not technical support. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company

Comment: @MichaelMainer user voice request: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/35049175-put-edit-mime-email-content-with-microsoft-graph  thanks.

Comment: I’m intrigued as to the use case here. What do you want to change about the email? Couldn’t you take a copy of the item and make changes to the copy? You may need to use EWS to achieve what you’re looking to do.

Comment: @sasfrog use case requires put/edit for original email as we do not want the content of original email to be accessible to user, unfortunately cannot share more. We work with O365 and we need to stick with the Graph, I am not sure EWS is possible way, can you please share more details?

Comment: Up vote this feature request at https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/35049175-put-edit-mime-email-content-with-microsoft-graph